# Silverlight TextBox text clarity doesn't match TextBlock clarity - why?

Tags: xaml, silverlight-5.0

I'm setting the following text options globally in a Silverlight 5 app:

```
TextOptions.TextFormattingMode = Display
TextOptions.TextHintingMode = Fixed
TextOptions.TextRenderingMode = ClearType
```

This renders TextBlock elements with much clearer text.

However, the TextBox doesn't seem to pick up these options, so at the same font size and family (Segoe UI 13px), the text is much grainier. The options are definitely being inherited, I've checked that.

Is this just an inbuilt limitation of the Silverlight TextBox? Or is there a workaround to get the same result as for the TextBlock? Ideally we want the text to look the same everywhere, regardless.

EDIT:

I tried setting UseLayoutRounding to False, which fixes the problem for the initial display of the control, but as soon as I select or edit the text, it goes back to the initial grainy quality.

Answer (score 0):

Would the property "VisualTextRenderingMode" solve the issue you are facing?